# ASP.NET Web Service - Illegal characters within the parameter

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web

Dears, I have an ASP.NET 2010 web-service with a method that accepts String parameter.

And I gone through a problem of including special characters within the passed string to the web service when invoked from the client side.

My Question:

What are the special characters that are not allowed to be within the parameter string? And how to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a setting in the IIS or the plesk app